# "Your input ran out of data" always at step # of epochs

Tags: keras, dataset, generator, tensorflow2.0, python-3.8

I have been trying to make my first data generator for a model.fit() with Keras. The dataset I'm trying to make has two inputs, an image and a float value. All of my image names and values are stored in a csv file. I believe I made my generator incorrectly because **no matter what my batch size is, I always get the error "Your input ran out of data" at the step equal to my epochs**. So if my epochs are set to 100 my model will run until it reaches step 100. My dataset is about 100000 images/values big. If anyone could help me find a solution that would be great.
I am currently using:
python 3.8
tf-gpu 2.4.0rc1
keras 2.4.3
pandas 1.1.4

Code:

```
IMG_SIZE = 400
Version = 1
batch_size = 64
val = .05

val_aug = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)
aug = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1/255, 
        rotation_range=30, 
        width_shift_range=0.1, 
        height_shift_range=0.1, 
        shear_range=0.2, 
        zoom_range=0.2, 
        channel_shift_range=25, 
        horizontal_flip=True, 
        fill_mode='constant')


df = pd.read_csv('F:/DATA/Vote/Vote_Age.csv')

df = df.sample(frac = 1)
cut = int(len(df) * val)

train_df = df[cut:]
val_df = df[0:cut]
print(f'Training dataset: {len(train_df)}')
print(f'Val dataset: {len(val_df)}')

train_steps = int(len(train_df) / batch_size)
val_steps = int(len(val_df) / batch_size)

def data(df, generator, batch_size, IMG_SIZE):
        z = 0
        while True:
                df = df.sample(frac = 1)
                for i in range(int(len(df) / batch_size)):
                        images, ages, votes = [], [], []
                        for x in range(batch_size):
                                csv_row = df.iloc[(z), :]
                                z += 1
                                image_path = f'F:/DATA/Vote/Images/{int(csv_row[0])}.jpg'
                                image = cv2.resize(cv2.imread(image_path), (int(IMG_SIZE), int(IMG_SIZE)))
                                image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                                image = image.reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)
                                generator.fit(image)
                                image = generator.flow(image, batch_size=1)
                                image = image.next()
                                image = image.reshape(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)

                                images.append(image)
                                ages.append(csv_row[1])
                                votes.append(int(csv_row[2]))

                        images = np.array(images)
                        ages = np.array(ages)
                        votes = np.array(votes)
                
                        return [[images, ages], [votes]]

#########
#Model was very big and unnecessary to include
#########

train_dataset = train_data(train_df, batch_size, IMG_SIZE)
val_dataset = val_data(val_df, batch_size, IMG_SIZE)

model.fit(
    x = train_dataset[0],
    y = train_dataset[1],
    validation_data=(val_dataset[0], val_dataset[1]),
    steps_per_epoch=train_steps,
    validation_steps=val_steps,
    callbacks=earlyStop,
    epochs=100, batch_size=batch_size,
    workers=multiprocessing.cpu_count(),
    verbose=1)

model.save(f'F:/DATA/Vote/Models/YiffModel{Version}')
```

Ouput:

```
...
  83/1484 [>.............................] - ETA: 4:46 - loss: 7578.7731
  84/1484 [>.............................] - ETA: 4:46 - loss: 7575.5172
  85/1484 [>.............................] - ETA: 4:46 - loss: 7572.2818
  86/1484 [>.............................] - ETA: 4:46 - loss: 7569.0662
  87/1484 [>.............................] - ETA: 4:46 - loss: 7565.8702
  88/1484 [>.............................] - ETA: 4:45 - loss: 7562.6932
  89/1484 [>.............................] - ETA: 4:45 - loss: 7559.5349
  90/1484 [>.............................] - ETA: 4:45 - loss: 7556.3948
  91/1484 [>.............................] - ETA: 4:45 - loss: 7553.2726
  92/1484 [>.............................] - ETA: 4:44 - loss: 7550.1679
  93/1484 [>.............................] - ETA: 4:44 - loss: 7547.0802
  94/1484 [>.............................] - ETA: 4:44 - loss: 7544.0094
  95/1484 [>.............................] - ETA: 4:44 - loss: 7540.9549
  96/1484 [>.............................] - ETA: 4:43 - loss: 7537.9164
  97/1484 [>.............................] - ETA: 4:43 - loss: 7534.8937
  98/1484 [>.............................] - ETA: 4:43 - loss: 7531.8863
  99/1484 [=>............................] - ETA: 4:43 - loss: 7528.8939
 100/1484 [=>............................] - ETA: 4:43 - loss: 7525.9163
WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 148400 batches). You may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset.
WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 78 batches). You may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset.

1484/1484 [==============================] - 30s 15ms/step - loss: 7250.9988 - val_loss: 13595.9355
C:\Users\Tristan\anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:2325: UserWarning: `Model.state_updates` will be removed in a future version. This property should not be used in TensorFlow 2.0, as `updates` are applied automatically.
  warnings.warn('`Model.state_updates` will be removed in a future version. '
2021-01-05 15:37:04.425018: W tensorflow/python/util/util.cc:348] Sets are not currently considered sequences, but this may change in the future, so consider avoiding using them.
C:\Users\Tristan\anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py:1402: UserWarning: `layer.updates` will be removed in a future version. This property should not be used in TensorFlow 2.0, as `updates` are applied automatically.
  warnings.warn('`layer.updates` will be removed in a future version. '
WARNING:tensorflow:FOR KERAS USERS: The object that you are saving contains one or more Keras models or layers. If you are loading the SavedModel with `tf.keras.models.load_model`, continue reading (otherwise, you may ignore the following instructions). Please change your code to save with `tf.keras.models.save_model` or `model.save`, and confirm that the file "keras.metadata" exists in the export directory. In the future, Keras will only load the SavedModels that have this file. In other words, `tf.saved_model.save` will no longer write SavedModels that can be recovered as Keras models (this will apply in TF 2.5).

FOR DEVS: If you are overwriting _tracking_metadata in your class, this property has been used to save metadata in the SavedModel. The metadta field will be deprecated soon, so please move the metadata to a different file.
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
```

Comment: I guess the error occurring at step 100 is related with the epoch number:100. There might be some issues with data dimensions. Sorry for not being much help.

Comment: @krenerd Changing the epochs to 105 got me to 105 steps. Great observation, this will help in troubleshooting. Thanks.